# Find a windows control using partial NameProperty in windows automation

Tags: c#, windows, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm trying to identify a windows static text control using a partial NameProperty. Here's the code I have:

```
// Get a reference to the window
AutomationElement epoWindow = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "MsiDialog"));
// Get a reference to the control
AutomationElement epoControl = epoWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, controlText));
```

I currently need the full controlText string for this to work but I'd like to search for a part of that string and return any controls found.
How do I do this?
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on a child collection with the prefefined [TrueCondition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.automation.condition.truecondition.aspx), like this:

```
  foreach(AutomationElement child in epoWindow.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, Condition.TrueCondition))
  {
      if (child.Current.Name.Contains("whatever"))
      {
          // do something
      }
  }
```

PS: You want to carefully choose the [TreeScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.treescope.aspx) if you don't want to kill the performance of your app (if it has a big children hierarchy) or wait indefinitely...

Comment: Will this break if your UI is translated? I believe the Name fields are not static for other languages.

Comment: I think it depends on how it was programmed. You can use the inspect.exe tool from the SDK to check that easily.